# How to implement methods for custom subelement in lxml?

Tags: python, lxml, lxml.objectify

I'm trying to implement xml composed of custom objectified elements with methods. But subelements seem to lose methods associated with them.

In particular, this works:

```
from lxml import etree, objectify
M = objectify.ElementMaker(annotate=False)

class A(objectify.ObjectifiedElement):
    def insert_b(self, text):
        self.B = M.Whatever(text)

some_xml = A(A())
some_xml.insert_b("Text")
etree.tostring(some_xml)
```

Output:

```
b'<A><A/><B>Text</B></A>'
```

But this doesn't:

```
>>> some_xml.A.insert_b("Text")
Traceback (most recent call last)
    ...
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'insert_b'
```

The result I expected was `b'<A><A><B>Text</B></A><B>Text</B></A>'`.

Is there a way I can implement that?